# spring-boot-starter-data-solr what version of solr-core compatible

Tags: solr, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.4.0.M3 and spring-boot-starter-data-solr without any version in pom file and solr-solrj also without any version (it picks up 5.5.1 version) . Would like to include solr-core also for that I had to mention the version  ,if I add version 6.0.0 or 6.1.0 the project compiles ,but during runtime it fails when I tried to create SolrConfig object with below error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.common.util.Utils.fromJSONResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigOverlay.<clinit>(ConfigOverlay.java:176)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.getConfigOverlay(SolrConfig.java:383)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.getOverlay(SolrConfig.java:891)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.getSubstituteProperties(SolrConfig.java:880)
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:150)
at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:90)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:187)
```

Tried lowering the solr-core version ,but it fails during compile time itself.  Is there a compatibility metric between solr-solrj ,solr-core and spring-boot-starter-data-solr

Answer (score 0):

You should use 5.5.1. The Solr modules are released as a "set" where the same versions are all intended to be used together. Specifically, `solr-core:5.5.1` depends on `solr-solrj:5.5.1`

Comment: Thanks for the response. That fixed the issue